# Overriding a function in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to temporarily override the **kill-new** function.  I have a way I want to reimplement kill-new that works in only in certain contexts, but I don't want to reimplement a special version of **kill-region** on top of that.  (kill-new is called from kill-region)

Since Emacs Lisp uses dynamic scoping, this should be possible, right?  (On the other hand, it seems that this would be an unsafe thing to support, and it might make me a bit nervous knowing that it is possible...)

I have experimented with using let and fset, but so far have found no way to get it to work as expected.  So, hopefully someone can fill in the blank in the following pseudocode:

```
(defun my-kill-new (string &optional replace yank-handler) 
   (message "in my-kill-new!"))

(defun foo ()
   (some-form-that-binds-a-function (kill-new my-kill-new)
   (kill-region (point) (mark))))
```

What should **some-form-that-binds-a-function** be?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
(defadvice kill-new (around my-kill-new (string &optional replace yank-handler)) 
   (message "my-kill-new!"))


(defun foo ()
  (progn (ad-enable-advice 'kill-new 'around 'my-kill-new)
     (ad-activate 'kill-new)
     (kill-region (point) (mark))
     (ad-disable-advice 'kill-new 'around 'my-kill-new)
     (ad-activate 'kill-new)))
```

Comment: I think I prefer this to using flet for this purpose.  

Though there is more ceremony in doing it using advice, it gives me easy access to the existing implementation of kill-new.

Comment: You probably want to remove the advice with an unwind-protect, so that nonlocal exits also remove the advice.  Just use flet.

Comment: @kes If you want to access the original definition of `kill-new`, just `flet` it to `old-kill-new`.

Answer (score 17):

Your `some-form-that-binds-a-function` is called `flet`, so you were close.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `advice` package, which is very good at doing all of this.

Comment: FYI: nowadays `advice` has been superseded by `nadvice`.

Comment: I'm running the bleeding emacs, and nadvice isn't there, but advice is still going strong.

Comment: That's surprising. Unless by "isn't there" you meant `nadvice` doesn't have all the features of `advice`? https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/emacs-lisp/nadvice.el

Comment: Ahh, still called "advice", and still documented as such.  So it's there, but it's "newer".  Nice.

Comment: Indeed. The newer system accomplishes the same thing as the old system, but "with fewer bells and whistles". I.e., it is more intuitive, works in more cases, is more consistent, and is simpler. Someday `advice.el` will be deprecated, although not anytime soon most likely.