# Temporarily overriding a function in Emacs Lisp

Tags: function, emacs, let-binding

I would like to override a function, but only when it is called from another specific function. Following the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2406814/5397009), I wrote the following:

```
(defun zzz/original () (message "Original func"))

(defun zzz/uses-original () (zzz/original))

(defun zzz/wrapper (f &rest r)
  (cl-flet
      ((zzz/original
        ()
        (message "Replacement func")))
    (apply f r)))

(advice-add #'zzz/uses-original
            :around
            #'zzz/wrapper)
```

I expected that calling `(zzz/original)` would keep printing `"Original func"` (it does), and that calling `(zzz/uses-original)` would print `"Replacement func"` (it doesn't: it still prints `"Original func"`).

Note that if I inline the contents of `zzz/uses-original` instead of calling it through `apply`, then I get the expected result:

```
(defun zzz/wrapper (f &rest r)
  (cl-flet
      ((zzz/original
        ()
        (message "Replacement func")))
    ;; Following is a copy of the code from `zzz/uses-original':
    (zzz/original)))
```

So what am I doing wrong, and is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: You're looking for `cl-letf`, eg. `(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'zzz/original) (lambda nil (message "Replacement func")))) (apply f r))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Rorschach, what I want can be done using `cl-letf` instead of `cl-flet`:

```
(defun zzz/wrapper (f &rest r)
  (cl-letf
      ((zzz/original
        ()
        (message "Replacement func")))
    (apply f r)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a partial solution just after posting: using `flet` from the `cl.el` package instead of `cl-flet` works:

```
(require 'cl)

(defun zzz/wrapper (f &rest r)
  (flet
      ((zzz/original
        ()
        (message "Replacement func")))
    (apply f r)))
```

However this triggers a deprecation warning about `cl.el`, so I'm still looking for a non-deprecated solution.